# Apt-get update and sources.list

Tags: updates, 14.10, software-sources

First of all, I'm complete linux noob. Please keep explanations simple )

I'm using 14.10 (Utopic unicorn,  I believe) on Virtualbox. I've run into cascade of problems with JDK installation (inability to fetch some archives), which led me to run apt-get update. It fails in a similar fashion, not being able to download some packages (some of them do come through).

Quick run around here led me to believe that the problem lies in sources.list. I need some help with either correcting it, or generating anew. I've tried to use repogen.simplylinux.ch, but it doesn't seem to work with 14.10.

Help plz :P

Comment: Ubuntu 14.10 reached end-of live on 2015-07-31 and isn't supported any more. Please upgrade to a more recent version.

Answer (score -1):

You could try this:

```
sudo -i
sudo apt-get update --fix-missing
```

if this dos not work you could try this:

```
sudo -i
sudo apt-get install thunar
thunar
```

and delete the sources.list file and run system settings, and then update and hatch the upper chronical, and then reload and it might work fine this way.